Interpreting log transformed variables in a regression
I am very confused about the interpretation of log transformed variables in a regression. For example, I have a log-level model with a B0=4.95 and B1=-1.07. So my model would be log(y)=4.95 - 1.07X. According to some sources on the internet, this can be interpreted as a 1 unit increase in X will give me a 107% decrease in Y. However, looking at my actual data this makes little sense:
e.g, , when x=1, f(1) = exp(4.95-1.071)= 48.2, when x=2, f(2) = 16.44. So the % change when increasing by 1 unit is (-65%). Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

the percentage interpretation iss valid for small changes (delta x * coefficient). So eg if you change x to 1.02, you get a 0.02 * -1.07 change

Thank you. But I am still confused. So if I have f(1)=48.2 and f(1.02) = 47.2 the %change in Y would be 2.1%, so I am still unclear on how to interpret the coefficients.

which is approximately 0.02 * -1.07= -2.14%

But is it normal that there are slight differences between the delta x*coefficient and the actual %difference in Y?

yes the (Taylor) approximation gets better for smaller and smaller changes, (and worse as you saw for large changes)

thank you! what about an interpretation ln(y) = 2.2*ln(x) + 4, 2.2 is the beta

One percent increase in x is associated with a (beta) percent increase in y."... where again its only for small percentage changes in x..
